# Decal in my if in my controller on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cart

I have a problem, i store a price in session in function of qty in my Cart, but i have a problem because its decal of -1 i have the price of qty 2 and i want to show the price of qty 3.

This is the code of my update function in my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $rowId)
    {
        $data = $request->json()->all();

        $validates = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'qty' => 'numeric|required|between:1,26',
        ]);

        if ($validates->fails()) {
            Session::flash('error', 'La quantité doit est comprise entre 1 et 26.');
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Cart Quantity Has Not Been Updated']);
        }

        $cptransport = Session::get('cp');
        $cp = substr($cptransport, 0, -3);
        $transport = Pricepallet::where('dep_end', $cp)->firstOrFail();
        $totalpanier = Cart::count();

        if ($totalpanier == 1) {
            $pallet1 = $transport->pallet1;
            $request->session()->forget('pricet');
            $request->session()->put(['pricet' => $pallet1]);
            Cart::update($rowId, $data['qty']);
        }

        if ($totalpanier == 2) {
            $pallet2 = $transport->pallet2;
            $request->session()->forget('pricet');
            $request->session()->put(['pricet' => $pallet2]);
            Cart::update($rowId, $data['qty']);
        }

        if ($totalpanier == 3) {
            $pallet3 = $transport->pallet3;
            $request->session()->forget('pricet');
            $request->session()->put(['pricet' => $pallet3]);
            Cart::update($rowId, $data['qty']);
        }

        Session::flash('success', 'La quantité du produit est passée à ' . $data['qty'] . '.');
        return response()->json(['success' => 'Cart Quantity Has Been Updated']);
    }
```

Thx and sorry for my english

Comment: apparently you're updating the qty after getting the price. so yeah the price will be if the previous qty. and "decalé" is "shift" in english :)

Comment: What's your exact question about this? Where does the code go wrong? And what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: This is solved thx i have make the condition in my view ^^ thx for the tips for the word

Answer (score -1):

There is no code to store or view price. So there is no way to detect the problem.
You have to share the code of store price, or view of it.